# Independent series for highcharts with color and gray background

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How to have the series with color and gray series work independently.
If you click on the radio button from the fiddle example, part of the chart is grayed out and rest is colors. I want to show the legend with colored and also gray color.

`London - blue
London - gray`

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgj7sfhp/24/)

```
$(function () {
    var grayblue = '#1D1D1D';
    var grayred = '#4C4C4C';

    dataLondon = [ 48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2];
    dataBerlin = [ 42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]
    highcharts(dataLondon, dataBerlin, 0);

    $(':input[type="radio"]').on("click", function() {
         selected = 12 - $(this).val();           
            tempLondon = [];
            tempBerlin = [];
            for(var i in dataLondon) {
                bLondon = {};
                bBerlin = {};
                if(i >= selected) {
                   bLondon['y'] = dataLondon[i];
                   bLondon['color'] = grayblue;
                   tempLondon.push(bLondon); 
                } else {
                   tempLondon.push(dataLondon[i]);
                }                
            }
             for(var i in dataBerlin) {
                bLondon = {};
                bBerlin = {};
                if(i >= selected) {
                   bBerlin['y'] = dataBerlin[i];
                   bBerlin['color'] = grayred;
                  tempBerlin.push(bBerlin); 
                } else {
                   tempBerlin.push(dataBerlin[i]);
                }                
            }

        highcharts(tempLondon, tempBerlin, selected);
    });
    function highcharts(dataLondon, dataBerlin, number) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ],
            plotBands: [{ color: '#ADADAD',
                from: -0.5,
                to: number - 0.5
            }]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        colors: ['#0000FF', '#FF0000'],
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'London',
            data: dataLondon

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: dataBerlin

        }]
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: So you want 4 legend elements? London Grey, London Blue, Berlin Grey, Berlin Red?

Comment: @Ondkloss yes, I tried to add two more series to the existing one

Comment: Indeed, you should add more series to the chart, simple implementation for you: http://jsfiddle.net/hgj7sfhp/28/ - note I'm using `stacking: "normal"`, to display two series in the same place. We can use that because data is disjointed properly.